# How to find static python libs with find_package(pythonlibs 2) in CMake

Tags: cmake

I printed  ${PYTHON_LIBRARY} out, it's [ /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so ]

but what i actually need is [ /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.a ]

i don't find some options like [Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS], so what can i do?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?